# tunnel into an SSH (not through ssh)

Tags: ssh, remote-access

Where I am located, I don't have access into a specific ssh host (through GIT) and I want to know if its possible to tunnel into it through something like proxy (even though proxy doesn't work with ssh). Can I SSH into one host and connect into another through the previous one's tunnel? Or something similar?

Comment: Hope this answer helps [http://superuser.com/a/727510/242890](http://superuser.com/a/727510/242890)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you need something like the following

```
ssh -L 2222:host1:22 -L 2223:host2:22 -L 2224:host3:22 user@middlehost
```

This is a command that you run on your local machine.  `middlehost` is the host you are able to log into from your local machine with `ssh user@middlehost`.  `host1`, `host2`, `host2`, are machines that you would like to log into but cannot from your local machine, but you can from middlehost.

After you have run the above command you need to run the following on your localhost to, for example, log in to `host2`

```
ssh -p 2223 user2@localhost
```

port 2223 is automatically forwarded to middlehost, where the original command forwards it to port 22 of host2.  From the PoV of host2 it is middlehost that is ssh-ing to it.