# Access Internal Network IP through another computer

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn

So I have ssh access to my desktop computer at work, I use Endpoint security VPN on my mac to connect to the desktop computer. Which works great, I can access most internal IPs through this VPN. However there seems to be internal IPs that I can only connect to on my Desktop PC at work.
Is there anyway I can use my desktop computer at work to act as an in-between, to send traffic that I request from my home computer and then forward it to the actual internal server and send the result back to the home computer?

I have tried searching on here and google but either don't understand the results or have a feeling that it wasn't what I was looking for. I have been looking into ssh tunnelling but not sure if that is what I'm looking for.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya you can use `SSH Tunneling` to achieve this. Let us assume that your machines are `macbook`, `desktop` and `internal_box`. `internal_box` can only be SSHed from `desktop` machine. Then you first create the tunnel on your `macbook` to `internal_box` via `desktop` using

```
ssh -L 2222:internal_box:22 user@desktop
```

Thsi will open port `2222` on `macbook` and forward all the packets to `2222` via `desktop` to port `22` of `internal_box`. So now `internal_box` is avilable at port `2222` of `macbook`

So you can connect to `internal_box` using

```
ssh user@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

If the above `SSH` succeeds, then you are connected to your ``internal_box`on your`macbook`via`desktop`. Hope that helps.